# redux form Selecting Form Values from nested array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

im trying to do react app using redux forms 
first i did structure like in the picture [JSON structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JF5b.jpg) by following Field array example from redux-form website

next i followed: Select form value example to get different fields to pop up. I tested it in root and worked like a charm.

but i cant seem to get values to pop up in my nested array.
any idea?

i asked this orginally in redux forms github and got answer:

> You need to select the entire name e.g. tagContainerInfos[0].hasEmail not just hasEmail. To do this, you may need to extract your Field array children into a separate component and use hasEmailValue on each of those individually.

but i dont really get it how should i do it.

```
function myFunction(fields) {
    x++;
    fields.push({})
    console.log(x);
    console.log(fields);
}



let rendertagContainerInfos = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }, hasEmailValue }) => (
    <ul>
        <li>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => myFunction(fields)}>Add tagContainerInfos</button>
            {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
        </li>
        {fields.map((tagContainerInfos, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
                <button className="btn btn-lg btn-success"
                    type="button"
                    title="Remove tagContainerInfos."
                    onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
                />

                <h4>tagContainerInfos #{index + 1}</h4>

                <div>
                    <label>Favorite Color</label>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor={`${tagContainerInfos}.hasEmail`}>Has Email?</label>

                        <Field
                            name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].hasEmail"}
                            id="hasEmail"
                            component="input"
                            type="checkbox"
                            onClick={() => console.log(tagContainerInfos)}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>



                {hasEmailValue &&
                    <div>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <div>
                            <Field
                                name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].email"}
                                component="input"
                                type="text"
                                placeholder="Email"
                            />
                        </div>

                    </div>} <Field
                    name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].messagetype"}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="messageType"
                />

                <Field
                    name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].interval"}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="interval"
                />
                <Field
                    name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].storageSize"}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="storageSize"
                />
                <Field
                    name={"protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[" + x + "].resetTags"}
                    type="text"
                    component={renderField}
                    label="resetTags"
                />

            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>


);
```

and here is my connect:

```
  rendertagContainerInfos = connect(state => {
  // can select values individually

   let hasEmailValue = selector(state, 
   "protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[0].hasEmail");
   console.log(hasEmailValue);
   return { 
   hasEmailValue

  };
```

----------------UPDATED MY CODE--------------
added function to add x value everytime when creating array.
now it works somehow JSON structure is like it should be. Problem now is that fields seem to be connected. when i type to one example email field also email field in tagContainerInfo[0] will have same typing.

heres picture to makes thing clear dont know if i made myself clear.
[new problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SL1V.jpg)

Comment: your `hasEmailValue` should be outside `meta`, like - `({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed }, hasEmailValue })` can you print what `tagContainerInfos` is? it should be like `tagContainerInfos[0]`

Comment: yea i changed that. tagcontainer prints out : protocolInfos[0].plcInfos[0].tagContainerInfos[0] i updated my code. and it allmost works now

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use back-ticks for string interpolation here - just use the value like this:  `name={ tagContainerInfos.hasEmail }`.

Comment: it gives me: `tagContainerInfos is not defined` if i do that. i updated my code and working good until i add new array. JSON structure is good but now when typing 
to fields it will type to all the fields in same  array